# Rails what does this "yield" do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view, yield

What does the yield do in this snippet?

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".sidebar">
  <!-- Your timezone is <%= Time.zone %> -->
  <!-- <%= "Ruby Version is #{RUBY_VERSION}" if Rails.env =~ /test|development/ %> -->
  <%= render partial:'shared/account_status' %>
  <%= render partial:"shared/session_timeout" %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= render partial:"shared/branding" %>
    <%= render partial:"shared/nav", locals:{icons:icons, actionable_urls:actionable_urls, top_level_items:MenuItem.top_level_items_with_access_rights_for_user(current_user).sort{|a, b| a.sequence <=> b.sequence}, current_item:current_navigation_item} %>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div id="content">
      <%= render partial:"shared/flash", object:flash %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

  </div>
  <%= render partial:"shared/ldap_user_menu" if signed_in_as_ldap_user?  %>
</body>
```

**SOLUTION**

see @Christian_Rolle 's answer below

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield. Try googling next time.

Comment: it will display the view based on the current route you visit via browser.

Comment: Did any answer helped you? Then please mark the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reserved Ruby key word **yield** is for processing closures (like a Proc or lamda). That said it is some kind of placeholder for processing some logic.
In Ruby on Rails view templating it is used for merging in partials. In the case of a layout file like the application.html.erb it merges in controller response templates like index.html.erb or show.html.erb.
Think of it as a placeholder for your controller response HTML in a global layout environment.

---

Read more at: [Understanding yield](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield)
or about Ruby closures:
[Do the Proc! ... a Ruby closure](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2014/06/do-proc-ruby-closure.html) and 
[Have a lambda! ... a Ruby closure](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2014/07/have-lambda-ruby-closure.html)

Answer (score 1):

okay ... lets talk about it in easy way , yield is like a placeholder or like a container . And while you make different parts of view and want to show it on any specific layout file , then you can just call that part on the yield section . And this is all it does .